# Regex removes code from between "<" and ">"

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I have an issue where I need to find a string in a file, but when I run the regex.match function it returns the string without any text between "<" and ">" missing.  Here is my code and the string returned

Original string - `[$iif{len("Test")>0,<meta name="Author" content="Test">,""}$]`

regex Pattern -  `\[\$[a-zA-Z_0-9\{\}\(\)<>=\|/\."",\s]*\$\]`

result - `[$iif{len("Test")>0,,""}$]`

```
'Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx for explanation on this reg expression 
regex.pattern = "\[\$[a-zA-Z_0-9\{\}\(\)\<\>=\|/\."",\s]*\$\]"

set matches = regex.execute(psTemplateData)

for each m in matches
    response.write m & " index - " & m.FirstIndex  & " " &  m.length & "<br />"
next
```

What is funny is that the match has the correct string length for the original string.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Wade

Comment: You can include angle brackets in your question if you enclose them in backticks, for code markup.

Comment: backtick as in `\`` around your string to display the angle brackets. Or just select the string and hit the code button or CTRL+K to format it. I just edited your post to display it correctly.

Comment: I misunderstood his comment, but I have fixed it.  Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex seems fine. My guess is your browser shows you `[$iif{len("Test")>0,,""}$]` because the `<meta name="Author" content="Test">` portion is being interpreted as HTML and thus disappears.

You'll need to encode the output so those angle brackets become `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Look at the `Server.HTMLEncode` method.

Comment: That was it, sometimes it doesn't pay to get out of bed.  Thanks.